# Bulleted list along with an HTML table

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying a bulleted list in an HTML table as follows.

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: decimal;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><li>Description</li></td></tr>
            <tr><td><li>Description</li></td></tr>
            <tr><td><li>Description</li></td></tr>
            <tr><td><li>Description</li></td></tr>
            <tr><td><li>Description</li></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</ul>
```

This however does not display a bulleted list properly on different browsers.

On Google Chrome (36.0.1985.143 m), it displays as expected.

[image]

On FireFox (31.0) however, it displays the list as follows.

[image]

On Internet Explorer (8), the list is shown as follows.

[image]

Is it an invalid mark up to nest a table inside a `<ul>`? Can this list be displayed on all major browsers as indicated by the first snap shot?

Comment: That's invalid HTML. Only LI can be a child of UL

Answer (score 0):

`list-style-type` only works with `display:list-item`

> **list-style-type:**
>   Applies to:   elements with 'display: list-item'

**Ref**

[list-style-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type)

[The ul element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)

> **ul element**: Content model: Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/618g9pmm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid to markup a table within a list - or anything that's not an expected `list-item` because it can cause undesired results ( okay that was kind of a BS answer, but it's a list, looking for list-items NOT wrapped in table elements. Technically, it could work, but you'd have to get more clever than you'd need to to get what you want).

You can achieve the listed effect if you work with a combination of `list-styles` on the `table` elements - just need to strip out the `<ul>` and `<li>`s and move the actual list-styles to the `<tr>`s

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Description</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tbody tr {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: decimal;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
tbody tr > * {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Just needs to be `table` parent specific so it knows to number the children as list items. 
Check it out @ http://jsfiddle.net/1j82y55y/